# "City air," or "city feel?"

Tags: phrases

> The neon signs brought a **city feel/city air** to the countryside.

Which alternative is more adequate? Or is there a better option?

The example above means  that *the neon lights made the countryside feel like the city.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are acceptable.

An 'X Feel' accurately describes any sort of situation where something feels as though it is like the subject in question.

An 'x air' has a similar meaning, because one of the meanings of the word "[air](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/air)" is "A peculiar or characteristic impression; an aura", which is what you are trying to say.